# special symbols in filename doesn't display correct in mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have code:

```
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('some html text');
    return $mpdf->Output("123!@#$%^&*()_+<><?:}{P}" . '.pdf', 'I');
```

But when I save document in filename instead symbols  `<>?:` displays `-----`.
Can it be fixed?

Comment: I believe some Unix file systems allow any character in file name, even asterisks or line feeds (at least that was true some years ago) but most other file systems don't. What's your OS and, more important, why do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: System is linux mint 17. Maybe it is not good idea, but I should do it

Comment: Still, browser will try to prevent you from shooting yourself in your foot.

Comment: I found, what if I try to save this file in FF, browser revert file name into 'document.pdf'. And it is bot good

Comment: I suspect the only reason is "customer asked for it". Sorry, some times customers ask for stuff that doesn't make any sense for the technical standpoint because they're simply not aware of the underlying issues. You'll have to explain them politely that there are certain characters you simply cannot use in file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this question has nothing to do with PDF generation. You want to create a file system object with a name that includes characters that have a special meaning in some shells:

- `<` is the input redirecton operator
- `>` is the output redirection operator
- `?` is the *any character* wildcard
- `:` is the Windows drive letter separator

And to you want to accomplish it through an additional layer you don't have control over (I assume a web browser).

Some file systems (not all) treat object names as raw byte strings and do not impose any condition. I recall being able to create files in an old Unix box that contained a `*` character and a line feed, after I read a book that explained such thing was possible. However, a file name goes though several software layers, many of which actually need to understand the name, and some of them will possibly impose additional restrictions to those of the file system itself. So, even if you manage to create the file, you might not be able to read it back later.

For this reason, the browser actively removes problematic characters. In some cases, it might be overzealous (`:` is safe on Unix) but it just tries to prevent potential issues (e.g. the Unix file is emailed or copied to a Windows share) and there's nothing you can do on the server to avoid that.